How do I make a bone in the IK static?
I am having a problem with this model of a robotic leg that I made where the IK rotates the whole leg, including the foot. I would like the foot to always be pointing down to the floor, but dont know how to :c


Edit: If I move the IK one unit up, when rotating the leg, I would end up with the following:

It would be great if I could enable it to only follow the rest of the leg's rotation on the z-axis

hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

it doesnt let me :/

It seems that you don't want to make the foot static. You just don't want it to rotate. In that case, I suggest to move the IK constraint one bone up which means making the foot the controller (target of the IK constraint). Note that you can limit the rotation of the controller which seems to be what you want. For this to work the parent of the foot needs to be cleared.

